# VLAN is not working in Virtual Box

Tags: server, virtualbox, virtualization

I had tried VLAN creating a VLAN pool in between the virtual boxes. But even after installing VLAN in client box, despite all the interface configurations, it is not pinging the other system in the same VLAN.

I had created a bridged interface for pinging the outer world and another intnet internal network for interconnecting the virtual boxes, in both the machines.

Virt boxes are pinging each other thorugh other interfaces, it is pinging outer world through the main interface eth0. Still not communicating via the VLAN interface. What is the reason behind it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is meant to be informative. It was hard to find out an answer for this question from other online resources.

While using the provided adaptor types in virtual box, this issue arises.
VLAN tag is stripped is because the Intel adapters support VLAN tagging and needs to be set in the adapter properties. When you don't provide such tag, the default is used (untagged). If you don't have the VLAN tab in the adapter properties, you haven't installed the advanced features of it.

Hence don't use the Intel PRO/1000 family of adaptors, because they will strip the VLAN tags. Instead, either use the Paravirtualized Network adaptor old default of AMD PCNet FAST III, neither of which seem to have this restriction.

When I provided para-virtualised adapter settings, this started to work.